# Getting ClassNotFoundException for ConcurrentReferenceHashMap while JDBCtemplete Update operation

Tags: spring-mvc, jdbc, sql-insert, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am using following implementation in springmvc jdbctemplete to insert a record,

```
int rowChanged = dbTemplete.update(new PreparedStatementCreator() {

        @Override
        public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection con) throws SQLException {
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(SQL.INSERT_ITEM);
            ps.setString(1, item.getItem_name());
            ps.setString(2, item.getItem_desc());
            ps.setString(3, item.getItem_rate()+"");
            ps.setString(4, "0");
            ps.setString(5, item.getCategory_id());
            ps.setString(6, item.getUser_id());
            return ps;
        }
    });
```

however I am getting following exception during execution,

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.util.ConcurrentReferenceHashMap
```

I would really appreciate some insight what is causing it.

Comment: which version of spring you are using?This class is present in spring 3 and higher version

Comment: well spring modules are 3.1.1 but spring-jdbc jar is 4.3.1

Comment: Thanks man solved it. version mis-match.

Comment: Hey guys I am new to this forum. Please help to mark some response helpful and close the question.

Comment: @Angan, you can detail out what have you done to resolve the problem as an ANSWER and accept it yourself, that will be it! Can help others with the same problem too!